# Finding no of working days excluding sunday in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have datediff() in ms sql server .
I want to find no.of 'Working' days(except Sunday) between the two days.
e.g. If i use datediff(day,'2014-05-01','2014-05-31') then it should give day count excluding Sundays

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
declare @d1 datetime,@d2 datetime
set @d1='2014-05-04'
set @d2='2014-05-18'

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @d1, @d2) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @d1, @d2))
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @d2) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) -- discard sundays
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17998)</kbd>

Comment: It will fail in some corner cases like:
StartDate ='2014-05-05' and EndDate='2014-06-2'. Answer that the query returning is 24 where as the actually is 25.

Comment: now it check for StartDate ='2014-05-04' and EndDate='2014-05-31'. This happens when the StartDate or EndDate is a Sunday.

Comment: Sorry:).. but now check for StartDate ='2014-05-05' and EndDate='2014-05-31'.

Comment: oops ! one last time :) the sat was also counted!

Comment: what if i simply do DATEDIFF(D,@d1,@d2)- DATEDIFF(wk,@d1,@d2) ?  Will it affect my desired result?

Comment: can you give an example for the same?

Comment: `declare @d1 datetime,@d2 datetime
set @d1='2014-05-13'
set @d2='2014-05-19'

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @d1, @d2))
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @d1, @d2))` should be 6? but returns 5?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one will work fine:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-05-01',
        @EndDate DATE = '2014-05-31';
DECLARE @RenamingDays INT = DATEDIFF(D,@StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@EndDate)) % 7;
DECLARE @NoOfWeeks INT = DATEDIFF(D,@StartDate,DATEADD(DAY,1,@EndDate)) / 7;

;with cte as
(
    SELECT @EndDate Dates,
           0 i
    WHERE @RenamingDays > 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, Dates),
           i + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE i + 1 < @RenamingDays
)
,WorkingDays AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(Dates) RenamingWorkingDays
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEPART(dw, Dates) != 7
)
SELECT @NoOfWeeks * 6 + RenamingWorkingDays
FROM WorkingDays
```

Comment: hmm... try `SET @d1='2014-05-11';
SET @d2='2014-05-18';` and what should be if `set @d1='2014-05-11'
set @d2='2014-05-12'`